# How can I install an x86 (Intel) version of python alongside other native ARM interpreters using pyenv?

Tags: python, x86, apple-m1, pyenv, apple-silicon

Im on a Macbook Pro 14" with an M1 Max thus on an ARM platform. Im using native pyenv and its python interpreters. For certain reasons, I would like to install an x86/Intel version of python alongside all of my other (native ARM interpreters). Is there a way in which I can do that? Or maybe install it by itself but connect it under pyenv? Anything?